# JNI C++ undefined reference to

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

i have the following JNI bridge, the bridge compiles and JNI is known to be working but when compiling the C++ code i get errors. Not sure what to do. Android Studio Doesn't mark anything wrong with the code.

```
extern "C" {

class Singleton {
private:
    Singleton();

public:
    static Singleton &instance() {
        static Singleton INSTANCE;
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    std::string something = "123";

    void setSomething(std::string some) {
        this->something = std::move(some);
    }

    std::string getSomething() {
        return this->something;
    }
};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_jni_JniGcode_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject jniGcode, jstring file_path) {

    Singleton::instance().getSomething();
    Singleton::instance().setSomething("blabla");
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_jni_JniGcode_something(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    Singleton::instance().getSomething();
}

}
```

the error that im getting:

```
In function `Singleton::instance()':
/{redacted}/file.cpp:34: undefined reference to `Singleton::Singleton()'
```

Comment: Well, you've declared a private constructor that takes no arguments, but where is the corresponding definition?

Comment: I don't know. Im a noob. I should create a h file for Singleton?

Comment: Changing `Singleton();` to `Singleton() = default;` might be the easiest solution.